# Disable Android Beam and NFC

Tags: android, nfc

I want to disable Android Beam when my NFC activity that implements CreateNdefMessageCallback is not in the foreground.  Currently I use when the activity loses focus:

```
        if(mNFCAdapter!=null)
        {
           mNFCAdapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this);
           mNFCAdapter.setNdefPushMessage(null, this);
           mNFCAdapter.setNdefPushMessageCallback(null, this);
        }
```

However, every activity in my application still starts the Beam when a NFC device is discovered.

Any alternative methods?

Answer (score 0):

In all activities in which you want to disable Android Beam add to `onCreate()`:

```
if(mNFCAdapter!=null) {
 mNFCAdapter.setNdefPushMessage(null, this);
 mNFCAdapter.setNdefPushMessageCallback(null, this); // optional
}
```